# How to simulate a tap event on iPad

Tags: debugging, screenshot, tap, ipados

I'm writing a simple script allowing to take screenshots of a physical device in debug mode attached to a computer and send tap events to control it.

For Android, the adb seems to be doing the job well with commands like:
`adb shell input tap x y`, my question is: is there a similar tooling available to take screenshots and send input events programmatically to an iPad ?